# JQuery callback works intermittently

Tags: jquery, ajax, nginx, flask, gunicorn

Please I am having a problem with a flask based app running on gunicorn using nginx as a proxy. A JQuery callback of mine works intermittently. It worked without fail in development. My development environment is flask running on windows. The intermittent behavior started the moment I moved to my deployment environment as described above. My callback code is as follows:

```
            $.getJSON("compute", data={'customer_orders':orders_string},function(data) {
                $("#result").val(data.result);

                var optimize_routes = data.result;
                alert("optimize_routes: " + optimize_routes);
                .....
                .....
            });
```

The getJSON method submits to a flask script and the callback is meant to fetch a string, the flask code is as follows:

```
            @app.route('/compute',methods=['POST', 'GET'])
            def compute_paths():

                orders = request.args.get("customer_orders")
                ......
                ......

                return jsonify(result=routes_string)
```

I would be very grateful for suggestions for how to make the callback run witjout fail in the deployment environment.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not that the callback is working intermittently, it's that the request is failing. Check the console when this behaviour next occurs. Most likely there will be an error in the console and you can debug the request response code and status

Comment: You can also test for [`.fail(() => {})` too](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Sorry for taking a while. The project had been put down and I had to get it back up. You are referring to the web console of the browser right? In the web console I have an error about an undefined variable. The app is an openstreetmap that i can click textboxes on and submit their data and the boxes locations. The undefined variable is the one that holds the map. I think its undefined because of the order of execution of the javascript code. By the time the boxes have been created and their values ready to be submitted, the map variable has been assigned its value.